# Angular Material datepicker filter specific date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-material

Can someone please explain how to apply a custom date as a filter using Angular Material without causing everyweek on that day to be selectable?

I've followed the documentation and can get it to work for the specific day of that week, yet it causes every week of the same day to be filtered. All the documentation appears to highlight this as a necessary feature for allowing/not allowing a user to select a specific date using the datepicker.

Comment: show us what yah got so far, please.

Comment: I've literally created a custom date within the 'onlyWeekendsPredicate' function in the JS area following this link from the official docs - https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker

Comment: Sorry, to make it easier - $scope.onlyWeekendsPredicate = function(date) { var day = date.getDay(); var specificDate = new Date("November 24, 2016"); var customDay = specificDate.getDay(); return date === customDay; };

Comment: so basically you'd like a filter that only lets you select weekends or weekdays?

Comment: I need to be able to disable specific dates actually, rather than the existing method that only is able to disable a specific day of each week.

Comment: with a specific day of the week or preferably exact days of a month?

Comment: Well it would simply be a day of the month in theory. Basically I'm looking to build a client an event booking calendar where customers will book an event on a specific date and then once approved by the client that date would then be unavailable for other customers to book. I've managed to find alternative fixes for this outside of Angular Material like Materialize, yet I was hoping to use Angular Material

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see below code. Basically, all I did was make an array of date's we'd like to allow. Then just used index of to check if the day was allowed. Additionally, you could write a function get current days in month and if user selects day then pop that day out of the currentDaysInMonth array. Here's my [codepen](http://codepen.io/tlombrana22/pen/qqmbqB?editors=1010). Hope it helps, I can update as needed.

```js
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache']).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myDate = new Date();

  $scope.minDate = new Date(
    $scope.myDate.getFullYear(),
    $scope.myDate.getMonth() - 2,
    $scope.myDate.getDate());

  $scope.maxDate = new Date(
    $scope.myDate.getFullYear(),
    $scope.myDate.getMonth() + 2,
    $scope.myDate.getDate());
  //if your dealing with day not formatted with some sort of timestamp
  // you can use a function like this to format then filter accordingly
  var daysAvailableThisMonth = [1, 15, 30];

  function formattedDate(day) {
    var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();
    var currentYr = new Date().getFullYear();
    return {
      day: new Date(currentYr, currentMonth, day),
      booked: false
    };
  }

  function getDaysInMonth(month, year) {
    var date = new Date(year, month, 1);
    var days = [];
    while (date.getMonth() === month) {
      //you can set the default flag as you like but itll help filtering.
      days.push({
        day: new Date(date),
        booked: true
      });
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return days;
  }
  var currentMonthDayArray = getDaysInMonth(new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getFullYear());

  daysAvailableThisMonth.forEach(function(day, index) {
    daysAvailableThisMonth[index] = formattedDate(day);
  });

  currentMonthDayArray.forEach(function(booking) {
    daysAvailableThisMonth.forEach(function(date) {
      if (date.day.getTime() == booking.day.getTime()) {
        booking.booked = false;
      }
    })
  });
  $scope.onlyWeekendsPredicate = function(date) {
    for (var i = 0; i < currentMonthDayArray.length; i++) {
      if (currentMonthDayArray[i].day.getTime() === date.getTime() && currentMonthDayArray[i].booked === false) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  };
});

/**
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved. 
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be foundin the LICENSE file at http://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/license.
**/
```

```html
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" class="datepickerdemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content layout-padding="">

    <div layout-gt-xs="row">
      <div flex-gt-xs="">
        <h4>Only weekends within given range are selectable</h4>
        <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" md-min-date="minDate" md-max-date="maxDate" md-date-filter="onlyWeekendsPredicate"></md-datepicker>
      </div>

      <div flex-gt-xs="">
        <h4>Opening the calendar when the input is focused</h4>
        <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" md-open-on-focus=""></md-datepicker>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div layout-gt-xs="row">
      <form name="myForm" flex-gt-xs="">
        <h4>With ngMessages</h4>
        <md-datepicker name="dateField" ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" required="" md-min-date="minDate" md-max-date="maxDate" md-date-filter="onlyWeekendsPredicate"></md-datepicker>

        <div class="validation-messages" ng-messages="myForm.dateField.$error">
          <div ng-message="valid">The entered value is not a date!</div>
          <div ng-message="required">This date is required!</div>
          <div ng-message="mindate">Date is too early!</div>
          <div ng-message="maxdate">Date is too late!</div>
          <div ng-message="filtered">Only weekends are allowed!</div>
        </div>
      </form>

      <form name="myOtherForm" flex-gt-xs="">
        <h4>Inside a md-input-container</h4>

        <md-input-container>
          <label>Enter date</label>
          <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" name="dateField" md-min-date="minDate" md-max-date="maxDate"></md-datepicker>

          <div ng-messages="myOtherForm.dateField.$error">
            <div ng-message="valid">The entered value is not a date!</div>
            <div ng-message="required">This date is required!</div>
            <div ng-message="mindate">Date is too early!</div>
            <div ng-message="maxdate">Date is too late!</div>
          </div>
        </md-input-container>
      </form>
    </div>

  </md-content>
</div>

<!--
    Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved. 
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be foundin the LICENSE file at http://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/license.
    -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, which seems to partly solve my problem by specifying date/s, yet the same days from the array are also disabled for all other months as well. I basically needed lets say one date, i.e. 23 November 2016. Thereafter, this date and only this date is disabled

Comment: @RichardAnsell have updated the pen, also included is a formatter for days  without some sort of formal timestamp.

Comment: Thanks for your help - solved the problem! Be great if the Angular team had this feature baked in as I've seen others asking about it. Seems to be same issue in Polymer also.

Comment: Hi again, could you take a quick peek at my code as I've changed it quite a bit and can't seem to be able to return the dates so they are disabled from different months rather than the same month: https://plnkr.co/edit/Fbe5pgKQUjDnTjXU4MoB?p=preview

Comment: Will have sometime around noon CST. Will check it out then.

Comment: Thanks again - managed to simplify the code a bit after realising my client will no doubt want dates unavailable in different months.

Comment: Where did you find the `md-date-filter` syntax? The documentation I found was talking about `mdDatepickerFilter`. Same thing, except the camelCase one doesn't work. (leaving this here for search engines to direct the mislead ones to here)